# Which component lifecycle method is best suited for performing side effects?

Tags: reactjs

Which component lifecycle method is best suited for performing side effects?

```
componentWillMount()
shouldComponentUpdate()
componentDidUnmount()
componentDidMount()
```

Comment: You should consider looking into `useEffect` instead. It combines all those into one https://www.reactjstutorials.com/react-basics/26/react-useeffect

Comment: and what is better, the question is exactly what is better of all this

Comment: @dparr that's assuming they're writing a functional component, which is unlikely considering their question on class-based component lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If talking class component lifecycle methods, `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` are the three lifecycle methods you should use for issuing side-effects.

- [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)
- [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)
- [componentWillUnmount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount)

If talking function components, then `useEffect` with an appropriate dependency array is what you would use for issuing side-effects.

- An `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array is roughly equivalent to `componentDidMount`.
- An `useEffect` hook with a populated dependency array is roughly equivalent to `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`.
- An `useEffect` hook with a populated dependency array and returned cleanup function is roughly equivalent to `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount`.

See [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) for more documentation